# GitLab CI for running test on main and merge_requests

Tags: gitlab-ci

I know that I could run test on main branch using:

```yaml
test:
  stage: test
  only:
    refs:
     - main
```

and for merge_requests using:

```yaml
test:
  stage: test
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

However under the `only` key, one is a map, and another a list.
Is there anyway to combine the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon inspection, I could use the rules key and create separate rules for `merge_request_event` and `main`.

```yaml
test:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: manual
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"'
      when: manual
```